# How can I plot a parametric curve in 3d space?

Tags: function, variables, plot, 3d, scilab

I have this curve:

```
x=cos(t);
y=sin(t);
z=t;
```

I want to plot it. How can I do it? I'm new in Scilab.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a look at the param3d function.

Comment: thank you for telling me about that command, now it is already solved